# R glmnet - appropriate link function for log-loss

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

I have a 2 class classification problem that I'm trying to optimize the log-loss for (not ROC/AUC).  I'm using the `glmnet` package in `R` but am unsure how to set the code up.

I'm assuming that the `family` argument should be `'binomial'` but am uncertain if I should use the `link = 'logistic'` or `'log'` and whether I need to adjust the `type.measure` argument.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The link function defines the relationship between the multilinear function of predictors and the expectation of the outcome; that is, what function does one transform $X\beta$ to be on the outcome's scale? The logistic function, because it describes the log of the odds ratio, is a standard choice with convenient interpretations, but any monotonic injective function $\mathbb{R}\to(0,1)$ is fine as a link function for binomial models.

Tuning an elastic net regression fit has little to do with the choice of the link function.

By default, `cv.glmnet` for a binomial likelihood will tune the magnitude of the penalty parameter $\lambda$ w.r.t. the penalized [deviance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_%28statistics%29) of the hold-out set of $k$-fold cross validation. This is probably what you intend to do, but I'm a little uncertain because I'm not sure how you're defining log-loss.